# How can i make vim automatically execute command after a time interval

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to make my vim automatically format my code and update the tag files rather than manually

Comment: Indenting often within seconds will reducr the preformance for large files

Answer (score 3):

You can do it automatically!
That's what `autocommand`s are meant for.

```
   :au BufEnter *.* gg=G
```

This will align your file whenever you enter into it.

```
  :au BufWrite *.* gg=G
```

This will align your file whenever you save it.

**what you want is the following**

A command like

```
   :au CursorHold *.* gg=G
```

will align whenever the cursor is idle. It depends on the update time. The update time is usually in milliseconds. (`:set ut?` will give you the update time)
For example, your script will be aligned every four seconds.(4000 milliseconds, is the default updatetime)

Comment: Out of curiosity. Don't you need to save and restore cursor position?

Comment: ggvG selects the entire file and aligns totally. Hence, I think there isn't any need to save or restore the cursor position. Did you had a y alternate ideas?

Comment: No, I just didn't have access to `vim` to check if it moves the cursor position to the beginning of the file each time, disrupting the user's workflow.